# WebView WON'T play when app in background

Tags: android

I've seen all over the web that people are having issues with the WebView, that it won't pause the audio when the app moves to the background.

I'm having the exact OPPOSITE problem. I WANT the audio to keep playing in the background, but it won't. I currently start a video on Youtube and if I turn off the screen (while the app is in foreground) it'll continue playing, but when I press the Home button, it stops playing.

Any ideas on why it doesn't have the, apparently, default behavior ?

Here's how I set-up my webview, in case it matters

```
public void setupWebView(Context ctx, ISlideWebView wv, IWebViewToParentComm listener,
                         File cacheFolder) {
    if (wv == null || !(wv instanceof WebView)) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Webview expected to be of type SlideWebView. Found class type [" + wv.getClass().getName() + "]");
    }

    SlideWebView webview = (SlideWebView) wv;

    WebSettings webSettings = webview.getSettings();

    webSettings.setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK);

    webSettings.setSaveFormData(false);
    webSettings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    webSettings.setSupportZoom(false);
    webSettings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
    webSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(false);

    webSettings.setAppCachePath(cacheFolder.getAbsolutePath());
    webSettings.setAppCacheEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setDatabaseEnabled(true);

    webSettings.setSaveFormData(false);
    webSettings.setSavePassword(false);
    webSettings.setGeolocationEnabled(true);//TODO: ?! AppConfig.getInstance(context).usesGeolocation
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
    webSettings.setDisplayZoomControls(false);
    webSettings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    webSettings.setUseWideViewPort(true);

    webview.setWebViewClient(new SlideWebViewClient(ctx, listener.getUrlNav(), listener.getUrlNavInterface()));
    webview.setWebChromeClient(new SlideWebChromeClient(listener));
    webview.setVerticalScrollListener(listener);
    webview.setOverScrollMode(View.OVER_SCROLL_NEVER);
    webview.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(false);

    FileDownloader fileDownloader = listener.getFileDownloader();
    if (fileDownloader != null) {
        webview.setDownloadListener(fileDownloader);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that I was testing it with youtube.com. I've since tested it using a website streaming radio music, and it works just fine. So apparently youtube.com or parhaps (haven't tested it) video's in general don't keep playing in the background.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah as you said webview issues are there playing in background.Even we had same issue but android api level specific. There are specific api calls `webview.pause()` and `webview.resume()`. These calls will specifically does javascript handling. We handled issues using these calls( lower version you need do with reflection).

So as per your javascript is handled at pause and resume, you  need make changes again as on Activity `onPause` callback call `webview.onResume()`

Comment: Yeah, actually a good idea. I just tried it. I called onResume on the webview when the Activity called onPause, but it seems it still stops the video from playing. :( Any other ideas?